# How to get to the good stuff?

Tags: support

I've got a bunch of tags for my profile that are related to my interests - but the questions that come up in my feed are always the latest ones and have no relation to my tags. Something seems not to be working right.

I've tried every option like 'hot', 'month', 'unanswered', trying to find an easy way to get through the stuff that's not relevant to me, but it makes no difference. On other stack exchange sites I tend to get stuff that's relevant to me.

Is there a way to get it to just give me a list of questions that have one or more of my tags, even if they are old, sorted to show most relevant and best rated first?

Comment: Can you post a list of what tags you have favorited and links to the unrelated articles that are showing up in your feed?  I'm not sure exactly how all that works, but it may help to have extra info to troubleshoot...

Comment: I have popular tags including adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, plus more specialist stuff I wouldn't expect to see regularly. When I asked the question there had been about 2 weeks of no relevant questions in the top 8 results - it's actually being quite well behaved today, the top 7 questions are all relevant. Maybe the problem is that there just isn't enough activity for there to be enough new material to show relevant stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviving this old question because [custom filters have been released recently. You can read more about how to use them here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?cb=1).

When you browse to the **Questions tabs** in the site, hit the **Filter** button.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to set up or achieve here - you mention feeds, but then ask about just getting a list of questions - so I'm going to try and cover the bases.

You can set up favourite tags using the little form on the sidebar:

[image]

Once you do that, questions with these tags will be highlighted on the front page of the site.

You can also [set up a filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters). You can specify the tags and sites you want to monitor. Each filter has a link at the bottom to its RSS feed.

Last but not least, you can just search for questions using tags. For example, typing in `[fonts]` in the search bar on the main site will turn up questions tagged [fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts).

Comment: Yeah, favourite tags is what I meant by "I've got a bunch of tags". By feed I meant the news-feed-like-block of questions on the main page - the central thing on the main page - not RSS feeds. And re. "Once you do that, questions with these tags will be highlighted on the front page of the site." - my question is about the fact this isn't happening.

Comment: @user568458 Ahha, thanks for the clarifications. Can you post a screenshot of what the front page looks like for you?